# Implicit Declaration of Function that Appears to be Definied

Tags: c++, c, atmel, texas-instruments

I'm porting the Texas Instruments SimpleLink driver to use with an Xmega host, and I'm getting a few implicit declaration errors when trying to build it.  I know what the error means, but as far as I can tell, it should be defined.  I must be missing something, I'm hoping someone can help me out.

Here is the error output, it's saying the function `CC3120Disable` is implicitly declared in the device.c file:

> Error      implicit declaration of function 'CC3120Disable' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]    Xmega Firmware  D:\CC3120SDK_1.55.00.42\simplelink_sdk_wifi_plugin_1_55_00_42\source\ti\drivers\net\wifi\source\device.c    173

device.c is pretty huge, so here are the includes, they are the very first thing in the file aside from comments:

```
#include <ti/drivers/net/wifi/simplelink.h>
#include <ti/drivers/net/wifi/source/protocol.h>
#include <ti/drivers/net/wifi/source/driver.h>
#include <ti/drivers/net/wifi/source/flowcont.h>
```

The first one (simplelink.h) starts a trail to where the function is declared, here is the first part of simplelink.h, again excluding the preamble comments:

```
#ifndef __SIMPLELINK_H__
#define __SIMPLELINK_H__

/* define the default types
 * If user wants to overwrite it,
 * he need to undef and define again */
#define _u8  unsigned char
#define _i8  signed char
#define _u16 unsigned short
#define _i16 signed short
#define _u32 unsigned long
#define _i32 signed long

#define _volatile volatile
#define _const    const

#include <ti/drivers/net/wifi/porting/user.h>

#ifdef    __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
```

user.h contains the macro definition that tells it to use the function `CC3120Disable`, and also an include that contains the declaration of that function.  Here is the first part of user.h, without the leading comments:

```
#ifndef __USER_H__
#define __USER_H__

#include "board.h"
#include "noos.h"
#include "SPI.h"

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <string.h>
```

and here is line 371 in user.h that defines the macro:

```
#define sl_DeviceDisable()             CC3120Disable()
```

Finally, here is all of my board.h file, which has the declaration of the function in question:

```
#ifndef BOARD_H_
#define BOARD_H_

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
#include <asf.h>
#include "SPI.h"

/* Typedefs */
//typedef void (*P_EVENT_HANDLER)(void* pValue);

/* Pins */
#define nHIB_PIN                IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTD, 7 )
#define CC3120_INT_PIN          IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTD, 6 )
#define CC3120_RESET_PIN        IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTA, 1 )
#define CC3120_SLAVE_PIN        IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTE, 0 )

#define LED_BLUE                IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTA, 5 )
#define LED_GREEN               IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTA, 6 )

/* USART pins */
#define USARTC0_XCK             IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTC, 1 )
#define USARTC0_TXD             IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTC, 3 )
#define USARTC1_XCK             IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTC, 5 )
#define USARTC1_TXD             IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTC, 7 )
//#define USARTD0_XCK               IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTD, 1 )
//#define USARTD0_TXD               IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTD, 3 )
//#define USARTD1_XCK               IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTD, 5 )
//#define USARTD1_TXD               IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTD, 7 )
#define USARTE0_XCK             IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTE, 1 )
#define USARTE0_RXD             IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTE, 2 )
#define USARTE0_TXD             IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTE, 3 )
//#define USARTE1_XCK               IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTE, 5 )
//#define USARTE1_TXD               IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTE, 7 )
//#define USARTF0_XCK               IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTF, 1 )
//#define USARTF0_TXD               IOPORT_CREATE_PIN( PORTF, 3 )

/* Functions */
void CC3120Disable( void );
void CC3120Enable( void );
uint8_t CC3120RegisterInterruptHandler( P_EVENT_HANDLER InterruptHdl , void* pValue );
void CC3120MaskIntHdlr( void );
void CC3120UnMaskIntHdlr( void );

void clock_init( void );
void init( void );

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* BOARD_H_ */
```

The function is defined in board.cpp, here is the beginning of that file, up to where the function is:

```
#include <asf.h>
#include "board.h"
#include "socket.h"

/* Variables */
P_EVENT_HANDLER     CC3120IrqHandler = 0;
uint8_t             intIsMasked = 0;

/* Interrupt Handler */
ISR( PORTD_INT0_vect )
{
    if ( CC3120IrqHandler && !intIsMasked )
        CC3120IrqHandler( 0 );
}

void CC3120Disable()
{
    ioport_set_pin_level( nHIB_PIN, false );
}
```

It's making me crazy, I can't figure out why it's throwing an implicit declaration error for that function.  Can anybody see a problem or suggest something to try?

Comment: does `device.c` includes `board.h`?

Comment: It's a nested include, device.c includes simplelink.h includes user.h includes board.h

Comment: If you are using gcc, you can execute it with `-E` to see what the preprocessor outputs. If `void CC3120Disable( void );` does not appear before the call first function calling it, then the compiler will warn you about that.

Comment: I would have thought this is a question for the development team for that library. Failing that, you're doing quite a good investigative job here - go further, produce a [MCVE] for yourself. You'll probably find the problem. I'm confident we won't be able to help you find it without one.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this error will not occur in C++ and all your source files are C - why is the C++ language tagged?

Comment: It's a C++ project, the driver is in C, the files in question just use C code.  Not sure if the C++ compiler would be causing the issue so I included the tag.

Comment: Can your compiler show the output of the preprocessor? I'd inspect that and see if the functions declaration appear at all. Perhaps the `BOARD_H_` guard is defined somewhere else and hence `board.h` is included but its contents are not in the preprocessed output.

Comment: I'm working on looking at the preprocessor output, I'm using Atmel Studio, which is a customized version of Visual Studio.  Haven't found anything telling yet.

Comment: I believe I figured it out, it looks like it's including a different board.h file that's buried in the avr includes instead of mine.  Thanks for the tip to look at the preprocessor output, that's how I found it.  No time to test at the moment, but I'm optimistic that I figured it out.  Thanks @Pablo

Comment: I hope that's the case, you can then rename your file. Like I said in previous comments, get the preprocessor output and look what really has been included.